# How to get process that was spawned by "open with" after shellexec

Tags: .net, shellexecute

I'm trying to clean up a temporary file that I've launched with a simple Process.Start(). I don't know what the type of the file will be, so I'm launching it using ShellExec = true:

```
var lProcess = new Process();
lProcess.StartInfo.FileName = lTempFileName;
lProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
lProcess.Start();

TempFileCleaner.RegisterCleanup(lProcess, lTempFileName);
```

However, the process resolves as "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rundll32.exe" (which is actually an Open With dialog). Once you choose an application in the open with dialog, the process exits.

**Is there a way to see which process is launched by rudll32 before it exists?**

If this is not possible, I'll have to read file associations manually and start the correct process myself, but I'll have to display an error if I can't find any associations.

I've also written this class to help with the cleanup:

```
    private static class TempFileCleaner
    {
        static Dictionary<Process, string> _PendingCleanups = new Dictionary<Process, string>();

        public static void RegisterCleanup(Process pProcess, string pFileName)
        {
            _PendingCleanups.Add(pProcess, pFileName);

            pProcess.Exited += pProcess_Exited;
        }

        static void pProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lProcess = (Process)sender;
            lProcess.Exited -= pProcess_Exited;

            try
            {
                File.Delete(_PendingCleanups[lProcess]);
            }
            finally
            {
                _PendingCleanups.Remove(lProcess);
                lProcess.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No. The Open With dialog might not even run a program (it might hand the document to an existing copy of the program). Actually, you have this problem already even without Open With. If your temporary file is a .docx file, you'll see that no new copy of WinWord is launched. If it is an .scf file, you'll see that no copy of *anything* is launched!

Comment: Wow, humbled to get an answer from you Raymond, thank you. Ok then, I'll go with the file association route. Why didn't you post that as an answer?

Comment: Bcause it isn't an answer; it just points out a flaw in the question. If you think it's an answer, then feel free to post it as an answer yourself and accept it.